# how to get rid of too many connections error

Tags: php, mysql

I am getting more of too many connections error , what's the solution for that problem , this is my error

```
     America/Chicago] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000] [1040] Too many connections' in /aaa/bbb/public_html/fol/Database.php:10
Stack trace:
#0 /aaa/bbb/public_html/fol/Database.php:10: PDO->__construct('mysql:host=loca...', 'aaaaa', 'aaa@20gdhh315', Array)
```

Comment: Are you sure you're closing all the connections you open?

Comment: should I assign Null to pdo object when i wanted to close connection ?

Comment: @Guns_Roses [Yes.](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.connections.php)

Comment: @Guns_Roses Yup. To quote [the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.connections.php): "To close the connection, you need to destroy the object by ensuring that all remaining references to it are deleted--you do this by assigning NULL to the variable that holds the object."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Mureinik said and without knowing your code , try to empty object (close connection) :

```
$mbd = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=prueba', $usuario, $contraseña);


$mbd = null;
```

Its good idea to use singelton for dealing with some concurrence  for example :

```
<?php

    class Dba

    {

        private $bdd = null;

        private static $_instance;

         

        private function __construct()

        { 

            $this->bdd = new PDO('mysql:dbname=test;host=localhost','root','');

        }

        

        public static function connexion()

        {

            if(is_null(self::$_instance))

            {

                self::$_instance = new Dba();

            }

            return self::$_instance;

        }

    }

?>
```

By this way you're checking if you have a previous instace of your Dba class and if not then you will create..

Hope i helped!!